# HUGO taxonomy links with conditional render

Tags: javascript, html, css, hugo

I want to add taxonomy to my static website, in a specific way.

[image: 1]

Need to render my blogs list page, based upon the categories refer image above (Technologies, A.I based software)

Also need these categories mentioned in the images are to be fetched from an markdown file, which will looped through and shown in categories partials.

My problem is I already have a pagination placed in the lists.html page, Now I need to render the article as per the selected category without disrupting the existing pagination.

> list.html page:

```
{{ define "main" }}

{{ partial "page-header.html" . }}

{{ partial "categories.html" .}}

<section class="section pb-0" data-aos="fade-in">
  <div class="container container-delta">
    <div class="row gy-3 justify-content-center">
      {{ $paginator := .Paginate (where site.RegularPages "Section" "in" site.Params.mainSections) }}

 <!-- Edit start -->
  {{ range .Site.Taxonomies.categories.techo }}
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 blog-card has-border">
        {{ .Render "article" }}
      </div>
   {{ end }}
 <!-- Edit end-->

      <!-- pagination -->
      <div class="col-12 pt-5">
        {{"<!-- pagination -->" | safeHTML }}
        {{ $paginator := .Paginator }}
        <!-- Number of links either side of the current page. -->
        {{ $adjacent_links := 2 }}
        <!-- $max_links = ($adjacent_links * 2) + 1 -->
        {{ $max_links := (add (mul $adjacent_links 2) 1) }}
        <!-- $lower_limit = $adjacent_links + 1 -->
        {{ $lower_limit := (add $adjacent_links 1) }}
        <!-- $upper_limit = $paginator.TotalPages - $adjacent_links -->
        {{ $upper_limit := (sub $paginator.TotalPages $adjacent_links) }}
        <!-- If there's more than one page. -->
        {{ if gt $paginator.TotalPages 1 }}
        <nav>
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center flex-wrap mb-0">
            <!-- Previous page. -->
            {{ if $paginator.HasPrev }}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link arrow" href="{{ $paginator.Prev.URL }}" aria-label="Pagination Arrow">
              <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
            </a></li>
            {{ end }}
            <!-- Page numbers. -->
            {{ range $paginator.Pagers }}
            {{ $.Scratch.Set "page_number_flag" false }}
            <!-- Advanced page numbers. -->
            {{ if gt $paginator.TotalPages $max_links }}
            <!-- Lower limit pages. -->
            <!-- If the user is on a page which is in the lower limit.  -->
            {{ if le $paginator.PageNumber $lower_limit }}
            <!-- If the current loop page is less than max_links. -->
            {{ if le .PageNumber $max_links }}
            {{ $.Scratch.Set "page_number_flag" true }}
            {{ end }}
            <!-- Upper limit pages. -->
            <!-- If the user is on a page which is in the upper limit. -->
            {{ else if ge $paginator.PageNumber $upper_limit }}
            <!-- If the current loop page is greater than total pages minus $max_links -->
            {{ if gt .PageNumber (sub $paginator.TotalPages $max_links) }}
            {{ $.Scratch.Set "page_number_flag" true }}
            {{ end }}
            <!-- Middle pages. -->
            {{ else }}
            {{ if and ( ge .PageNumber (sub $paginator.PageNumber $adjacent_links) ) ( le .PageNumber (add $paginator.PageNumber $adjacent_links) ) }}
            {{ $.Scratch.Set "page_number_flag" true }}
            {{ end }}
            {{ end }}
            <!-- Simple page numbers. -->
            {{ else }}
            {{ $.Scratch.Set "page_number_flag" true }}
            {{ end }}
            <!-- Output page numbers. -->
            {{ if eq ($.Scratch.Get "page_number_flag") true }}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a href="{{ .URL }}" class="page-link{{ if eq . $paginator }} active {{ end }}">
                {{ .PageNumber }}
              </a>
            </li>
            {{ end }}
            {{ end }}
            <!-- Next page. -->
            {{ if $paginator.HasNext }}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link arrow" href="{{ $paginator.Next.URL }}" aria-label="Pagination Arrow">
              <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a></li>
            {{ end }}
          </ul>
        </nav>
        {{ end }}
      </div>
      <!-- pagination -->

    </div>
  </div>
</section>

{{ partial "call-to-action-2.html" . }}

{{ end }}
```

> categories.html

```
<section>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light light-bar">
    <div class="container container-delta">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Technology</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">A.I based software</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Custom options</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

> article.html

```
<article class="card border-0 rounded-md overflow-hidden h-100">
  <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}" title="{{ .Title }}">
    {{ with .Params.image }}
    {{ if fileExists (add `assets/` .) }}
    {{$img:= resources.Get . }}
    {{$img:= $img.Resize "570x "}}
    {{$imgWebp:= $img.Resize "570x webp"}}
    <img loading="lazy" decoding="async" class="card-img-top h-auto" width="{{$img.Width}}" height="{{$img.Height}}"
      src="{{$imgWebp.RelPermalink}}" alt="blog-post" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='{{$img.RelPermalink}}'">
    {{else}}
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/570x321.png/eee/eee" alt="image-fallback">
    {{end}}
    {{end}}
  </a>
  <div class="card-body position-relative">
    <span class="badge text-white text-uppercase">{{ .PublishDate.Format "Jan 02, 2006" }}</span>
    <h3 class="h5">
      <a class="blog-title" href="{{.RelPermalink}}" title="{{.Title}}">{{.Title}}</a>
    </h3>
    <p class="mb-0">{{ .Plain | truncate 110 }}</p>
  </div>
  
  {{ with site.GetPage (string .Params.Author | urlize | lower) }}
  <div class="card-footer bg-transparent">
    <div class="card-author">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="user-image me-1">
          {{ if .Params.image }}
          {{ $img:= resources.Get (.Params.image) }}
          {{ $img:= $img.Fill "30x30" }}
          {{ $imgWebp:= $img.Fill "30x30 webp" }}
          <a href="{{.RelPermalink}}" title="{{.Title}}">
            <img loading="lazy" decoding="async" class="rounded-circle" src="{{ $imgWebp.RelPermalink }}" alt="author image" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='{{$img.RelPermalink}}'">
          </a>
          {{ else }}
          <i class="far fa-user-circle position-relative" style="font-size:26px;top:2px"></i>
          {{ end }}
        </div>
        <div class="user-info">
          <p class="font-weight-500 mb-0">{{i18n `by`}} {{if .Title}}<a href="{{.RelPermalink}}">{{ .Title }}</a>{{else}}<span class="text-muted">{{i18n `admin`}}</span> {{end}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{ end }}
</article>
```

**Edit:**

I have added this code in the list.html page.

```
   {{ range .Site.Taxonomies.categories.techo }}
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 blog-card has-border">
        {{ .Render "article" }}
      </div>
   {{ end }}
```

It works, but I have two issues

1. The pagination is not working (this part is really confusing me).
2. I have to provide categories.techo to show the items, how do i make the techo  part dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I've not unfortunately gone through your links to figure out the taxonomy structure you want. In the future I suggest you just lay that out in your question.

So I'm going to answer the question "Do you know how to make taxonomy structures in Hugo?" And here you go:

https://gohugo.io/content-management/taxonomies/

So in your site config:

```
taxonomies:  
  category: categories  
  tag: tags  
  philosophy: philosophies  
  author: authors
```

That's four taxonomies right there. Note: category and tags is out-of-the-box. But when you make new taxonomies, it overwrites them so you have to reinclude, if you want them, Ergo how I wrote this. Bien?

Then in the markdown for my post about Kantish thoughts on Hegelian Philosophy in early communist Estonia as interpreted by the Modern Society of Archaicness, I would write, in the front matter:

```
philosophies: 
- Hegelian
- Kant
authors: 
- Modern Society of Archaicness
- Communist Party
```

There you go...

Comment: I do have some idea about taxonomy in hugo, I did add the "taxonomies" (just categories) in my site config and respective category in the post1.md file and post2.md. But I when visit the list page fort that specific category all the articles are listed. I need to render only the categories provided in the post1.md and post2.md. Hope you understand, my problem. I could also provide any other info if you need.

Comment: Hello Alex. So, when you say "list page for that category" please clarify. Do you mean the Taxonomy page? The taxonomy term page? Or the list page for that folder/directory?

Comment: Hello Alex. So, when you say "list page for that category" please clarify. Do you mean the Taxonomy page? The taxonomy term page? Or the list page for that folder/directory?

Comment: So if your taxonomy is "kant" then the taxonomy page is /kant/
if you have a DIRECTORY /my-blogs/kant/ That is NOT the taxonomy page. IF you want to list the taxonomies IN that page then use this code: https://gohugo.io/templates/taxonomy-templates/#example-showing-content-in-same-series

Comment: Hi rogelio, If possible could you please look at the second issue I am facing now? updated in the question.

Comment: np. Pagination is a separate subject - try a new post. On the rest - I'm updating my answer now. - Actually - never mind - did you add Categories: -techo to from matter of a blog?